# ListView filtering with simple adapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm newbie in java and i've some problem with my code..

```
   ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Activity_ListView.this, list, R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{Config.TAG_NOMOR_INVENTARIS,Config.TAG_JENIS_BARANG,Config.TAG_NAMA_BARANG,
                    Config.TAG_MERK,Config.TAG_TAHUN,Config.TAG_NAMA_PENGGUNA},
            new int[]{R.id.nomorinventaris, R.id.jenisbarang,R.id.namabarang, R.id.merkbarang, R.id.tahunbarang, R.id.namapengguna});
   listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    /**
     * Enabling Search Filter
     * */
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            Activity_ListView.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

The problem is.., I want to use the adapter (on simple adapter) to onTextChanged method.. but the adapter on that method (onTextChanged) still red and it always said "can't resolve symbol "adapter""

Sorry for my bad english...
I would be very grateful if anyone wants to help me..

Answer (score 0):

You already defined and initialized 'ListAdapter adapter'. You can use

```
adapter.getFilter().filter(cs); 
//no need to use Activity_ListView.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
```

To use filter, you need to create custom adapter class and implements filterable. Ref: [Instant search with filter class](http://codetheory.in/android-filters/)